# Cloud Solution with custom Thumbnails

Tags: ios, document-management, cloud-service, cloud-storage

I am searching for a cloud solution (like "Dropbox", "Box" or "[Fluix](https://fluix.io/)") which lets you select **custom thumbnails** for files and folders. 
It should also have an **iOS-App** with synchronization and **offline availability**. 
I already looked at "Filecamp" which provides the [custom thumbnails](https://filecamp.com/support/look-and-feel/custom-thumbnails/) but no mobile app nor offline functions.

I hope you can help me to find this treasure.

Thanks.